# winforms control size limit

Tags: .net, winforms, controls

I am using a Panel's paint event to display a really long diagram. I've run into the problem of .net controls size (height and width) are silently limited to a signed 16 bit integer (32,767). I'm assuming this is an underlying win32 limitation.

**Is there a way to get around this limitation and have larger controls?**

Comment: May I ask what sort of data is this diagram showing that requires it to be nearly as wide as 23 wide screen monitors (depending on resolution)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to have your own scrollbars(rather than a scrolled panel), and then draw only the part of the diagram which is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Consider rendering a thumbnail view the length of your form (one screen), with a view rectangle indicating where you are.  Then just full-size render the part they scroll to.

Assuming you already have code that renders the whole DNA sequence, you might not even have to change much; the [Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) class has a [Clone()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx) method that appears to let you clone just a rectangular section of the Bitmap, and it also has a [GetThumbnailImage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx) method you can use to create your thumbnail.