# Windows.Forms.Panel 32767 size limit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an application that uses `Windows.Forms.Panel` to display a list of pictures. When the height of the panel exceeds 32767 pixels the rest of the content is simply cut off.

example:

```
Windows.Forms.Panel myPanel;

ArrayList pictureList;

foreach(pic in pictureList) {
    myPanel.Controls.Add(pic) // adds all the objects without complaints
}
```

In the example all elements are add to the panel without an error to be thrown, but after the panel has reached a size of 32767 no image is displayed anymore.

My question: Is it possible to break this limit and display more content in a panel?

I know that the approach is inconvinient in any way, but there is no time now to redesign the whole Application.

Comment: 32767 - is the max value for the `Int16` type, but `Size.Width` and `Size.Height` is of `Int32` type, about which size are you talking?

Comment: @sll I think he means myPanel.Controls won't take more than 32k items - urgh...

Comment: Windows itself packs height/width into a single 16 bit WORD, so your limited to 32767 in either dimension, you will have to work with the viewport area and display only what needs to be visible

Comment: @dave : But OP said `height of the panel exceeds 32767 pixels`

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/38954067-ca61-4ec3-b977-4a54d8a1052c/

Comment: possible duplicate of [winforms control size limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398485/winforms-control-size-limit)

Comment: The strange thing is, that in Windows xp32 the error does not occur. *crazy*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896073/adding-dynamic-controls-to-form-with-auto-scroll

Comment: You can always create new panel when the height exceeds certain limit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an architectural limitation in Windows.  Various messages that indicate positions in a window, like WM_MOUSEMOVE, report the position in a 32-bit integer with 16-bits for the X and 16-bits for the Y-position.  You therefore cannot create a window that's larger than short.MaxValue.  This isn't exactly a real problem, nobody has a monitor that's wider than 32,767 pixels and won't for a long time to come.

You'll have to do this differently.  Like using Graphics.TranslateTransform() in a Paint method.

Answer (score 2):

LPARAM - A Data type of Windows used to pass message parameters to Windows Procedure. It is a 32 bit pointer which passes message as two parts i.e in High order(First 16 bits of 32 bits) and Low order(Second 16 bits of 32 bits).

```
  Where 
       High order is used to pass the height of the control and
       Low order is used to pass the width of the control
```

So if the height or width of the control exceeds 32762size, it shows error because

32767 is the highest number that can be represented in a signed 16bit integer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution without a paint method

I had this exact problem. I didn't want to have to re-write functionality that was already coded into my child controls. This routine manages the child controls via a scrollbar, and keeps the out-of-play ones hidden and just offscreen.

```
Public Class ManuallyScrollingPanel
  Inherits Panel

  Public WithEvents sbar As New System.Windows.Forms.VScrollBar

  Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    Controls.Add(sbar)
    sbar.Visible = True
    Me.AutoScroll = False
  End Sub

  Sub SetScrollParams()
    If PanelPositions.Any Then
      Dim NewMax = CInt((From item In PanelPositions.Values Select item.Bottom).Max + 500) - Height
      If sbar.Maximum <> NewMax Then
        sbar.Maximum = NewMax
      End If
    End If
  End Sub

  Public Sub RegisterChildSize(pnl As Panel, DesiredBounds As Drawing.Rectangle)
    PanelPositions(pnl) = DesiredBounds
    SetScrollParams()
  End Sub

  Dim PanelPositions As New Dictionary(Of Panel, Drawing.Rectangle)

  Private Sub ManuallyScrollingPanel_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    sbar.Top = 0
    sbar.Left = Width - sbar.Width
    sbar.Height = Me.Height
    SetScrollParams()
    sbar.LargeChange = CInt(Height * 0.9)
    sbar.SmallChange = CInt(Height * 0.2)
  End Sub

  Private Sub sb_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles sbar.Scroll
    ScrollTo(e.NewValue)
  End Sub

  Private Sub sb_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sbar.ValueChanged
    ScrollTo(sbar.Value)
  End Sub

  Sub ScrollTo(pos As Integer)
    Me.AutoScroll = False
    For Each kvp In PanelPositions
      Dim VirtBounds = New Drawing.Rectangle(CInt(kvp.Value.Left), CInt(kvp.Value.Top - pos), CInt(kvp.Value.Width), CInt(kvp.Value.Height))
      If VirtBounds.Bottom < 0 Or VirtBounds.Top > Height Then
        ' it's not visible - hide it and position offscreen
        kvp.Key.Visible = False
        kvp.Key.Top = VirtBounds.Top
      Else
        ' Visible, position it
        kvp.Key.Top = VirtBounds.Top
        kvp.Key.Visible = True
      End If
    Next
  End Sub

End Class
```

Then, for each child control (mine were dynamically added, sounds like the OP was doing the same thing) make this call:

```
CType(Parent, ManuallyScrollingPanel).RegisterChildSize(Me, PanelObject.Bounds)
```

Note I pass in the child's bounds separately as I build the controls from DTOs to allow the same app+views to render as a web app and a windows app. Same with limiting it to panels. Refactor out as needed.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you add a scrollbar to your panel

just set AutoScrollbar = true

and just set the RightToLeft property to true.