# 32,767 pixel limit for autoscroll in winforms panel object?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

Is there a 32,767 pixel limit for autoscroll in winforms panel object? I am displaying pages (via page-sized panels) of a business document in a viewport created by an autoscrollable panel and when it exceeds 104 pages (adds up to about 32K height in pixels) they start overlapping!

Am I missing a setting or something? Is there a better control to use in Winforms? Is there a workaround?

### edit

I did miss something. The question was already answered! The Comma in my number prevented it from appearing in the convenient 'similar questions' list when asking:-/

## Answer

None of the duplicates actually have an answer - just explaining why it doesn't work. See this question for my answer:

[Windows.Forms.Panel 32767 size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064678/windows-forms-panel-32767-size-limit)

The answer suggesting translatetransform solves a different problem than the one I and the original poster of that question have (about windows controls themselves). There is a reason I do not paint directly - I use other functions of the native windows panels that I do not want to have to re-write or re-engineer which I would if I had to paint it myself.

Comment: It's a 16 bit integer and cannot exceed 32767. You'll have to find a different way to calculate top position.

Comment: Yes, there certainly is a limitation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064678/windows-forms-panel-32767-size-limit .