# Picturebox Location Wrong! vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I do not know if there is a limit in the form, the picture boxes are not in the position I set and I cannot select 595 Lines or above with the mouse in the list box.
Please watch the video for details.
Video = https://youtu.be/rEyuVu66G8Q

```
 For i As Integer = 1 To FOTOLAR.Items.Count

        Dim a As Integer
        Dim newPictureBox As New PictureBox()
        newPictureBox.Name = "PictureBox" & i
        newPictureBox.Location = New Point(1, 4 + a)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(4 + a)
        newPictureBox.Size = New Size(55, 55)
        newPictureBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        newPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage
        newPictureBox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255))
        Me.Controls.Add(newPictureBox)
        a = a + 55

        Dim stra As String = FOTOLAR.Items.Item(i - 1)
        Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream
        fs = New System.IO.FileStream(stra, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
        newPictureBox.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs)
        fs.Close()
        AddHandler newPictureBox.MouseDoubleClick, AddressOf picd_Click
        AddHandler newPictureBox.MouseClick, AddressOf pic_Click
        AddHandler newPictureBox.MouseDown, AddressOf picmd_Click
        AddHandler newPictureBox.MouseMove, AddressOf picmm_Click
    Next

Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    '  Button6.Location = New Point(1, 33609)
    For Each Pbox As PictureBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
        If Pbox.Name = "PictureBox612" Then
            ISIMLER.SelectedIndex = 612
            Pbox.BringToFront()
            MsgBox("wrong: " & Pbox.Location.Y) '32767
            MsgBox("Correct: 33609")
            If Pbox.Location.Y = 32767 Then
                Pbox.Location = New Point(1, 33609)
            End If

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: No one looks for videos here :( Otherwise it is Windows limitation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064678/windows-forms-panel-32767-size-limit and similar topics.

Comment: What is `FOTOLAR`. I am having trouble figuring out what kind of object has `.Items.Item(i - 1)` property/method.

Comment: Move `Dim a As Integer` outside the for loop.

Comment: Are the small images to the left of the list in the video the picture boxes? There appear to be repeat images.

Comment: @Mary `FOTOLAR.Items.Item (i - 1)`

FOTOLAR I used it to get the text value of the item with index number 0 in the listbox.
This number (i) increases with each iteration and I get the new text value on the next line. 

`Dim a As Integer` in the loop.   `a = a + 55`

Comment: `Are the small images to the left of the list in the video the picture boxes? There appear to be repeat images.` 
Yes, Each file has its own icon in the pictureboxes.

Comment: Okay, but what is FOTOLAR when it was declared? Is it a control? If so, what kind? Is it one of your classes? What is it?

Comment: FOTOLAR are a Listbox control and her name is FOTOLAR.